# Debugging an ajax call to a Python script

Tags: python, ajax, pydev

How do I get my Python script running in the debugger? I have a web app that is making an async ajax call to a python script. I want to be able to watch this python script in the debugger once the ajax call is made. How would I go about doing this?

I am developing with eclipse, and have Pydev installed. It seems like Pydev has a debugger, but I'm not sure how to make it wait for the script to run from the ajax call.

Comment: Have you tried adding logging to your Python script? By debugger, are you referring to the browser console?

Comment: Yes I have added logging. I want to be able to trace it as my browser hits the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PDB in the view that gets called by your AJAX call.

```
[...code...]
def view(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    [...code...]
```

then you can use this PDB to look at your code using a few commands like `p` which is a shortcut for `print`

```
p my_var  # displays the value of my_var
n  # executes statement and goes to next statement
c  # continue (in other words, the application will keep running)
q  # quit (exits the debugger by throwing an error (thus, not executing the rest of the code)
h  # prints help for PDB
```

Comment: That will work, but I'm just unsure of how to actually interact with it. It's a browser calling an ajax script. Is there a way to interact with it using chrome?

Comment: You're dealing with backend data. The data has been sent from your browser to the server, so you need to debug from the server since the browser doesn't have control over the backend (not directly).

Comment: If you want to debug javascript, `debugger` statements is the way to go, but that's only to debug your javascript

Comment: I want to debug the backend (python). Normally when you want to run pdb you just run the python script, and you can see it and interact with it in the terminal. How does this work with an ajax call calling the script, how can I debug it?

Comment: Use `pdb` as specified in the answer. Django will run normally until it processes the specific view.

Comment: I am not using Django. I'm using lighttpd, and I'm pretty sure that uses cgi.

Comment: You probably need a software in between lighttpd and your cgi script if you want to use pdb. I don't use cgi, so I can't help you much on that part.